# OS X 10.5 upgrade to OS X 10.7 with data saving

Tags: macos, upgrade, leopard

They gave me macbook for development, it's quite powerful, but I need to upgrade i to OS X Lion because otherwise I can't run Xcode 4.X. How to upgrade but to save existing data somewhere on the hard drive? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to upgrade without loosing any data, as long as you do **not** opt to have the HD erased or formatted prior to installing the OS, during the installation process.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought this is true only for one level upgrade...

Comment: 10.7 officially allows for direct upgrade down to 10.5.8.